# Convert mdb to mysql file

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ms-access

I need to migrate an Access `.mdb` database into a MySQL database. I have tried  [Access To MySQL](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php) and it works fine for me, as it generates a `dump.sql` file with the complete database structure and data, but I need to do this process programmatically from my WinForms VB.NET program.

Do you know any way to get this?